# Post request sent by CURL gets parsed correctly but when sent from postman, I get undefined data

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I am learning Node.js as a result I am setting up a authentication service. I have an issue parsing the body from post request.

This is my index.js file

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const db = require('./queries')
const port = 3000
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
)
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.json({ info: 'Node.js, Express, and Postgres API' })
})

app.post('/login',function(req,res){
  var username=req.body.username;
  var password=req.body.password;
  console.log("User name = "+username+", password is "+password);
  res.end("yes");
});
```

This is printed on the console:

```
bash-3.2$ node index.js 
App running on port 3000.
Username = undefined, password is undefined
```

But when i use CURL

```
curl --data "username=Jerry&password=jerry@example.com" http://localhost:3000/login
```

It works. Don't know why?

Comment: Is your index.js complete? Just starting your node server wouldn't cause the route to be called. I don't see how it would print out the following line with the route being called.

Comment: How do you mean? I am using postman for calling the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the postman header settings. Try changing the header content type value to application/json and change body to raw.